How to find the equivalent resistance in this circuit with only dependent source?
in the following circuit (nodes a,b are open circuited in the problem) I want to find \$R_{Th}\$ for ab.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
the way I learned is that we force some source with V_test and I_test, then we find the ratio of V_t/I_t to get the equivalent resistance. I've done this problem at least 3 times, and each time got a different answer and all are wrong, the answer is supposed to be 150 ohm. If anyone can solve and explain their steps I would appreciate it very much.

Can you show us the steps?

Let's first set up the circuit into LTspice and get an answer:

From the above, it's clear that \$R_{_\text{TH}}=\frac{200}{13}\:\Omega\approx 15.3846\:\Omega\$ (and that \$R_{_\text{TH}}\ne 150\:\Omega\$.)
I'd now like to see your own work product. Perhaps you did get the right answer.
If you show me something from your own process, I'll show you the simultaneous 3-equation solution to the above.
Added
The math I would use would follow KCL for the nodes (with your initially indicated direction for \$i_d\$):
parts = { r1:200, r2:50, r3:100, r4:150 }
kcld = Eq( vd/r1 + vd/r3 + vd/r4, va/r4 + vc/r1 )    # KCL node d
kcla = Eq( va/r2 + va/r4, vc/r2 + vd/r4 + i1 )       # KCL node a
eqvc = Eq( vc, 250*(vd - va)/r4 )                    # node c's voltage
solve( [ kcld, kcla, eqvc ], [ va, vc, vd ] )[va].subs( { **parts, i1:1 } )
200/13

With the opposite direction for \$i_d\$ then:
parts = { r1:200, r2:50, r3:100, r4:150 }
kcld = Eq( vd/r1 + vd/r3 + vd/r4, va/r4 + vc/r1 )    # KCL node d
kcla = Eq( va/r2 + va/r4, vc/r2 + vd/r4 + i1 )       # KCL node a
eqvc = Eq( vc, 250*(va - vd)/r4 )                    # node c's voltage (direction altered)
solve( [ kcld, kcla, eqvc ], [ va, vc, vd ] )[va].subs( { **parts, i1:1 } )
150

That's the way I'd arrange the equations for solution.

Hi, did you notice that if we change the i_d current direction we will get Rth = 150R.

this is exactly what i got, after talking with the instructors, it turns out they flipped the i_d current from the question but didn't update the answer, exactly like @G36 said.
thank you guys!

@JBH My intent was to encourage showing their work effort after which I'd show mine. I also have no idea what you mean by "real engineering" in this context. So I'd you would explain yourself better, perhaps I'd get your point better. Get wishes, regardless.

@JBH Added the math. Since the author selected and closed the question, it also seems appropriate that I add it, anyway.

I'm removing my down vote, but if you want an upvote, you need to convert all that to actual equations.

@JBH Already present in the code. Look at my many other answers for math I've written out. Unfortunately, in this case, it's still not clear enough which way I should write the $i_d$ equation. So I'd need to write it both ways. But the code provides what's needed. My entire goal in writing here was to encourage communication with the OP. That hasn't happened, sadly. And by the way, I am very much disinclined to care about up votes. Or down votes. I care about communication. You've offered that. That's what matters to me. Getting an upvote isn't any motivation to me. I just want to help.

Classical network analysis based on topology and with the method of node voltages:


+1 for showing real engineering.
